# What is format of this colors ?

Tags: color

I have some colors on paper whose specified color formats differ from the well-known web color formats. They begin with a letter of color then numbers which specify contrast like R143 R111 R100. R letter specify Red and others are same like G111 and Y121 are green and yellow

What is the name of this format? How can I translate it into well-known color formats?

Comment: Do you have any other color letters to share? I'd think it's the usual RGB scheme, with R as red with the usual range of 0-255, but it's hard to be sure with the information available. Might be some obscure spot color system too, but I've no clue about it. :-)

Comment: @Hrulga - i have updated answer

Answer (score 3):

I'd think the color codes are from some paint/pigment manufacturer's color chart, since that reference to yellow would make it a bit odd color system otherwise. Though it's possible there are more complementing colors in system, which would make it work better.

I checked one local paint manufacturer (in Finland), and they use a similar system for their swatches, letter and three-digit number code. But there can be as many systems as there are paint manufacturers. And in that case, it's not probably convertible to any regular color format without measuring the reflective color of the pigment mix itself.

Comment: I feel that you are right. It looks none-standart color format of a company.